# Make tree column not the first but second

Tags: tree, ag-grid

I'm not able to set the non-group column as the first column in the grid.

I've found only an ugly workaround for this:
params.columnApi.moveColumns(["usage"], 0);
but there is an animation that makes user experience a bit poor.

```html
  <ag-grid-angular
    style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"
    class="ag-theme-balham"
    [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
    [rowData]="rowData"
    [treeData]="true"
    [getDataPath]="getDataPath">
  </ag-grid-angular>
```

```js
...
export class ProcTreeComponent {
...
  columnDefs = [
    {
      field: 'usage',
      headerName: 'Usage'
    },
    {
      field: 'category',
      headerName: 'Category'
    }
  ];
  rowData = [
    {
      usage: 1.0,
      name: ['chrome'],
      category: 'Permanent'
    },
    {
      usage: 1.0,
      name: ['chrome', 'Google Chrome'],
      category: 'Permanent'
    }
  ];

  getDataPath = function(data) {
    return data.name;
  };

  constructor() {
  }
...
}
```

Actual order of the columns: Group, Usage, Category
Expected: Usage, Group, Category

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Why do you want to make a non-group column as the first column?

Comment: There is a very narrow column that I want to have there - and there it looks better.